# How to filter NSDate from a Core-Data Entity using NSPredicate

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate, fetch

I've got a Core Data Entity with a time stamp (`NSDate`) and I need to fetch records from the last *n* days. How could I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#define DAY_1 86400 //seconds in one day
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"<your entity name>" inManagedObjectContext:<your context>];
request.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp > %@",[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-DAY_1*n]];
NSFetchedResultsController *frc=[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request 
                                                                        managedObjectContext:<your context> 
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
[request release];
```

now you can use frc to perform the fetch